# Python test suite recording

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Castro to record my test suite using Python 3.6 after making many syntax changes in the config files I'm still getting the following error:

```
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib
```

Is there any method to port the lib module from Python 2.7 to 3.6 or does anyone know the source of a version of the Castro package compatible with Python 3.6?